# Recursing in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

To avoid blowing up the stack, i want to abandon the stack when recursing in javascript, one solution is to use setTimeout with the timeOut 0. Is there any other solution? thank you in advance.

I want to import a big array of users into database and call a callback when the job is done. This is the code :

```
function importUser(userBigCollection,callback) {
  (function addUser() {
   var record = userBigCollection.getOneRecord() ; //Pop one record from collection
   db.insert(record, function(error) {
        if (err) { callback(error); return }
        if (userCollection.empty()) {
          // All users have been created 
           callback();
         } 
    else {
    setTimeout(addUser, 0);
      }
   } })();
}
```

Thanks for your  reply!

Comment: what about the base case ? & why do you need setTimeout in order to abandon recursion ? Can you paste some code & explain what you are trying to acheive ?

Comment: If you don't need returned values from your recursive invocations (which had better be true if you're using `setTimeout()`, then you should be able to use a simple loop.

Comment: Also, `setTimeout` with zero delay implementing any kind of loop as you suggest is going to give horrible performance.

Comment: This depends on what you are trying to use recursion for. If you just want to recursively do some processing, then the setTimeout thing is an option. If you actually want to get an answer back, such as finding the nth Fibonacci number, you may need to re-factor into a loop. Can you post what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Trying to avoid stack issues by using `setTimeout()` with zero delay is like trying to avoid stabbing someone by instead using a sledgehammmer on them. It feels like you could just try to prevent your recursion from launching into space. Use a counter or something with a value that's close to what you expect will be required, to keep the stack trace low or redesign so you need less recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This recursive code will run for a maximum depth of 10 recursions:

```
function recursive(maxloops,othervars){
   if(maxloops==0) return FALSE;
   if(morerecursionneeded) return recursive(maxloops-1,othervars);
   return endofrecursion(othervars);
}

recursive(10,whatevervars);
```